# How to get metadata from a gRPC service method in Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, grpc, grpc-node

I have a gRPC service running like this:

```
server.addService(PassportService, implementation);
server.bind(mfeConfig().grpc.passport, grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
server.start();
```

I can call my service from a client like this:

```
const request = new GetConsoleUserRequest();
const meta = new grpc.Metadata();
meta.add('__.grpc.exchanged-token', token);
this.client.getConsoleUser(
  request,
  meta,
  (err: grpc.ServiceError, val: GetConsoleUserResponse) => {
```

But I can't figure out how to read the metadata in my service implementation. Now matter which overloads I define for `getConsoleUser`, the metadata is never one of the arguments. Here's `getConsoleUser`, which just returns some fake data:

```
getConsoleUser: (_req: GetConsoleUserRequest, callback: Function) => {
  const response = new GetConsoleUserResponse();
  const user = new ConsoleUser();
  user.setName('Bob Loblaw');
  // Change me to userStatus.GUEST to simulate anonymous user access
  user.setState(userStatus.REGISTERED);
  user.setEmail('bob@loblaw.com');
  response.setConsoleUser(user);
  callback(null, response);
},
```

I've tried changing that signature to this:

```
getConsoleUser: (_req: GetConsoleUserRequest, meta: grpc.Metadata, callback: Function) => {
```

But if I do that, the second argument is actually the callback function, and the third argument is undefined.

Is there a way to read the metadata from my service implementation? Or is there some other class that I have to attach my service to so that I can listen for incoming metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument passed to the server method is not a message object. It is a "call" object that has multiple different properties, including `call.metadata` to get the metadata, and for unary and server streaming methods, `call.request` has the actual request message. For streaming requests the call object is also a Node.js Stream object that you can write to and/or read from, whichever is relevant.

For more details, look at the `ServerUnaryCall` and `Server(Readable|Writable|Duplex)Stream` classes in the [API reference documentation](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/node/index.html).

Comment: Just the ticket! Thank you!!